# Generating tag cloud count given these 3 tables

Tags: sql, tags

I have these three table to store tags for photo albums.  Here is the schema

**table 1: Albums**
Album_ID
Album_Name

**table 2: AlbumTags**
Tag_ID
Tag_Name

**table 3: AlbumTagBridge**
ID
Tag_ID
Album_ID

What is the most efficient SQL to be able to come up with a result set that looks like this:

Tag_Name | Count
Tag 1    |  19
Tag 2    |   3
Tag 3    |  17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT dbo.AlbumTags.Tag_Name, 
       COUNT(dbo.AlbumTagBridge.Tag_Id) AS Cnt
FROM dbo.AlbumTagBridge 
INNER JOIN dbo.AlbumTags ON dbo.AlbumTagBridge.Tag_Id = dbo.AlbumTags.Tag_ID
GROUP BY dbo.AlbumTags.Tag_Name
```

Comment: I am assuming you don't care about the Albums but just tag counts across them all.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Tag_Name, COUNT(AlbumTagBridge.ID)
From AlbumTags
Join AlbumTagBridge USING(Tag_ID)
Group By Tag_Name
```

Grouping by `AlbumTags.Tag_ID, Tag_name` might possibly be a tad cheaper depending on your indexing &c (especially if your SQL engine isn't all that smart;-), but since you tell us nothing about your indices nor about your engine this is about the best we can do.

Comment: right now i have no indexing at all.  i am using SQL server 2008

Comment: This code also assumes that tag names are unique; i.e., that there are no two tags whose IDs are different but names are the same. I think this is a good assumption that should be enforced with a unique constraint.

Comment: running this query gives me an error:
"Tag_ID" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.

Comment: try `Join AlbumTagBridge ON AlbumTagBridge.Tag_ID = AlbumTags.Tag_ID` then -- not sure why it would object to `USING` but it seems it is!-)